# (r) turning data (DNAbin) into a matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to run stamppFst() and stamppConvert() with haplotype data. The data I have is a squence of nucleotides in a DNAbin. I have tried to find ways to turn it into a matrix but what I have read goes way over my head since this is the first time I have ever used R.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTjoA.png)

This is an example of one of the data sets I want to use.

I apologize if this is a very basic question. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format. You should also include all relevant code, libraries and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
reformatDNA  <- function(dna){
## DNAbin to matrix

temp <- matrix(as.character(dna),
               nrow=(length(row.names(dna))),
               dimnames=dimnames(dna))

## As DNAbin uses a bitCode, the codes must be translated to standard chars.

                              temp <- car::recode(temp,"'88'='A';
                                      '28'='C'; '04'='-'; '48'='G';
                                      '02'='?'; '18'='T'; 'f0'='N'")

                              temp<- as.data.frame(toupper(temp))
                              return(temp)
                              }
```